# How to add a javafx shortcut key combinations for buttons

Tags: javafx, keyboard-shortcuts

My UI has a adding button and I want to assign a keyboard shortcut combination for that. I have failed to use the setAcceleartor for this purpose. 
What is the easiest way to set up keyboard shortcuts in javafx applications?

button declaration in the UI:

```
 <Button fx:id="addButton" alignment="CENTER" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addAction" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="130.0"  text="Add"  HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
```

Controller button binding:

```
@FXML
private Button addButton;
```

The method that wants to setOnAction for the shortcut for the button:

```
    public void addAction(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    if (validateInput()) {
        String productName = productField.getText();
        double unitPrice = Double.parseDouble(priceField.getText());
        int quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityField.getText());
        double total = unitPrice * quantity;
        ITEMLIST.add(new Item(productName, unitPrice, quantity, total));
        calculation();
        resetAdd();
        productTableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        ObservableList<Product> productsData = ProductDAO.searchProducts();
        populateProducts(productsData);
        searchField.setText("");
    }
}
```

initialize() method:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
  setSaveAccelerator(addButton);
}
```

The code I tried with setAccelerator:

```
    private void setSaveAccelerator(final Button button) {
    Scene scene = button.getScene();
    if (scene == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("setSaveAccelerator must be called when a button is attached to a scene");
    }

    scene.getAccelerators().put(
            new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.S, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN),
            new Runnable() {
                @FXML public void run() {
                    button.fire();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code you tried for your accelerator? As I think this is the best way.

Comment: sure. I added it

Comment: In the method you posted, you get the scene of the `addButton`. Shouldn't it be changed to the `button ` argument?

Answer (score 4):

In your `setSaveAccelerator` method, instead of directly calling `addAction(ActionEvent event)`, just instruct the button to fire its event to its listeners such as: `button.fire()`. For example:

```
    private void setSaveAccelerator(Button button) {
        if(button==null) {
            System.out.println("Button is null! "); // check that the button was injected properly through your fxml
        }
        Scene scene = button.getScene();
        if (scene == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("setSaveAccelerator must be called when a button is attached to a scene");
        }

       scene.getAccelerators().put(
            new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.S, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN),
            new Runnable() {
                @FXML public void run() {

                    button.fire();
                }
            }
       );
   }
```

**EDIT**

To also avoid the `IllegalArgumentException` you must attach the accelerator after the button is attached to a scene. I managed to achieve this by creating a public method in the controller to attach the accelerator after the scene has been set. Then, in the class where the scene is loaded the controller's method can be called which sets up this functionality. See the example below:

In the controller class (in my case `MainController`):

```
public void setup() {
    setSaveAccelerator(button);
}
```

In your main class when loading the fxml file:

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(MainController.class.getResource("mainFXML.fxml"));
    AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

    MainController controller = loader.getController();

    Scene scene = new Scene(page);

    controller.setup(); // calls the setup method attaching the accelerators
```

**FULL EXAMPLE**

Main class:

```
public class Main extends Application{

    public static Stage primaryStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Main.primaryStage=primaryStage;

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(MainController.class.getResource("mainFXML.fxml"));
        AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        MainController controller = loader.getController();

        Scene scene = new Scene(page);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Shortcut example");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        controller.setup();

        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Maincontroller:

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private Button button;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane rootPane;

    @FXML
    private TextArea textarea;

    @FXML
    void action(ActionEvent event) {

        textarea.setText("Action fired!!");
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        assert button != null : "fx:id=\"button\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MainFXML.fxml'.";
        assert rootPane != null : "fx:id=\"rootPane\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MainFXML.fxml'.";
        assert textarea != null : "fx:id=\"textarea\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MainFXML.fxml'.";

    }

    public void setup() {
        setSaveAccelerator(button);
    }


    private void setSaveAccelerator(Button button) {
        if(button==null) {
            System.out.println("Button null!!");
        }
        Scene scene = button.getScene();
        if (scene == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("setSaveAccelerator must be called when a button is attached to a scene");
        }

        scene.getAccelerators().put(
                new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.S, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN),
                new Runnable() {
                    @FXML public void run() {

                        button.fire();
                    }
                }
                );
    }
}
```

MainFXML.fxml

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="rootPane" prefHeight="408.0" prefWidth="330.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="139.0" layoutY="350.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#action" text="Button" />
      <TextArea fx:id="textarea" layoutX="73.0" layoutY="38.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: It will have to be called when the button is created. Possibly in your `initialise()` method?

Comment: sure I did that. But this scene continues to throw a null pointer exception. It seems it doesn't get the scene that is attached to the addButton unless it is clicked. Is that it?

Comment: Could you add your `initialise()` method to the question? As well as the exception's stacktrace, indicating the line where the exception occurs.

Comment: sure. I edited the question and added the initialize() too.

Comment: I think the case is, the root element is still not placed on the scene when initialize() is called.

Comment: I extended the answer to ensure the scene is present before the accelerator is attached. I also added a statement to check if the button is null in the `setSaveAccelerator()` method. If that happens, then there's probably an error in the fxml.

Comment: problem is , if I call any of the methods that is associated with a  button within the initialize(), it gives a null pointer exception. From where should I call the certain method?

Comment: Can you verify that the button is null? As I did in the answer's setSaveAccelerator() method? If that is the case then there's a problem with how the button is injected from the fxml. Which is unrelated to your question.

Comment: As it is showed, I used @FXML annotation for binding the button and  onAction="#addAction" in the FXML to state the click action to call the addAction method when the button is clicked. I want this to be done without clicking, but using a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Yes I know. That is what is described in the answer, I tested it and got it working. What I am referring to is that if your button is null in the initialize method, then there is a problem with the injection.

Comment: I will check it out. Thanks.

Comment: Pleasure, I added my full example for reference.

Comment: PS if you are satisfied with the answer, you should mark it as the accepted answer for the question.